# How do I add an intermediate SSL certificate to Kubernetes ingress TLS configuration?

Tags: kubernetes

The documentation does not specify how to add an intermediate SSL certificate: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls

I suppose the next step would be to read the Kubernetes source code.

Comment: May be useful https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24669

Answer (score 21):

If you add multiple certificates in `tls.cert` key in Kubernetes TLS Ingress Configuration. Please do this like this

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<put your certificate value in a single line >
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN INTERMEDIATE CERTIFICATE-----
<put your certificate value in a single line>
-----END INTERMEDIATE CERTIFICATE-----
```

Otherwise, you'll get an error in ssl cert chain validation.

Always put main certificate first.

Comment: This doesn't work with google cloud, use only -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE----- as separators. Neither is necessary to put each certificate in a single line.

Comment: Tested today with GKE Ingress and K8s Secret. Works perfectly fine. Tested and verified with SSLLabs https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: I can confirm the comment from @4ndt3s it only works with that separator. I could not believe it.

Comment: Can confirm that this works with nginx-ingress controller running on GKE on GCP with a certificate created as @saran described and then loading it as a secret into the cluster

Comment: I dont think this actually exsits `-----BEGIN INTERMEDIATE CERTIFICATE-----` I have googled now for a while and could find any other example than yours. On top it didnt work for me. When I used `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` for the intermiedte on on the bottom it did work.

Comment: Only `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`  and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` in the crt or cert file are recognized.

Comment: Ensure a newline between certificates.

i.e between 

`-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

and 

`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

Answer (score 18):

It has to be appended to the certificate value. Just like nginx.

Comment: I created a new .crt file and put the contents of my `.crt` file at the top, then after that I pasted in the contents of my `.ca-bundle` file.

Comment: Do something like `cat example_com.crt example_com.ca-bundle > full_example_com.crt` and then pass the `full_example_com.crt` file to `kubectl` --cert argument ;)

Comment: Thanks you very much, I wish i found the answer as soon as.

Comment: What is meant with “same file”? And what is like nginx?

Comment: the certificate value basically

Answer (score 11):

Use this command to create a cert

`kubectl create secret generic tlscert_with_ca --from-file=tls.crt=your_cert.crt --from-file=tls.key=your_key.key --from-file=ca.crt=your_ca.crt`

BTW, `your_ca.crt` could be a intermediate cert as well

It works to me, the cert in nginx-inginx-controller should like this

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
your_cert
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
your_key
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
your_intermediate
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Reference [official doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/client-certs/)

Comment: this is not kube secert TLS (kubernetes.io/tls) but type: Opaque

Comment: Secret name needs to use dashes, not underscores. I got an "Invalid value" error on `tlscert_with_ca` with the following message:

"a lowercase RFC 1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')"

The "Secret" docs contradict this with:
"The keys of data and stringData must consist of alphanumeric characters, -, _ or ."

Answer (score 5):

Solution proposed by Saran works for me excepted that I had to remove "INTERMEDIATE" in the second part

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<put your certificate value in a single line >
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<put your **intermediate** certificate value in a single line>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Follow Saran's instruction => Always put main certificate first.

Answer (score 3):

The intermediary SSL cert (`ca.intermediate.crt`) is included as a second cert in the k8s `tls.crt` field.

`tls.crt` includes three files separated by `\n`: `server.crt`, `ca.intermediate.crt` and `ca.crt`.

Here is an Ansible task that sets-up the a cert:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
     wildcard_foo_com_ssl_tls_crt:
       - "{{ lookup('file', './ssl_certs/star_foo_com/server.crt') }}"
       - "{{ lookup('file', './ssl_certs/star_foo_com/ca.intermediate.crt') }}"
       - "{{ lookup('file', './ssl_certs/star_foo_com/ca.crt') }}"
     wildcard_foo_com_ssl_tls_key: "{{ lookup('file', './ssl_certs/star_foo_com/server.key') }}"

  - name: Set up foo.com Certs
    k8s:
      state: present
      definition:
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Secret
        metadata:
          name: name-com-wildcard-foo-com
          namespace: prod
        type: kubernetes.io/tls
        data:
          tls.crt: "{{ wildcard_foo_com_ssl_tls_crt | join('\n') | b64encode }}"
          tls.key: "{{ wildcard_foo_com_ssl_tls_key | b64encode }}"
          # ca.crt: this key seems to be ignored
```

Answer (score 3):

In your crt file add the certificates in the following order:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
{Certificate issued to you}
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
{Intermediate certificate}
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
{Root certificate}
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

To apply changes immediately, reboot the nginx controller (assuming you are using this ingress controller):

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx
```

Answer (score 2):

Assumption:
you have three files:

- privkey.pem
- root_cert.cer
- interm_cert.cer

1. `openssl x509 -inform DER -in root_cert.cer -out root_cert.pem -outform PEM`
2. `openssl x509 -inform DER -in interm_cert.cer -out interm_cert.pem -outform PEM`

if commands 1 and 2 are not working, the certificate files might be already in pem form. In this case, you could skip steps 1 and 2.

3. `cat root_cert.pem interm_cert.pem > full.pem`
4. `kubectl create secret tls tls-ssl-ingress -n ingress --cert=/path/to/full.pem --key=/path/to/privkey.pem`

The secrets (in step for its called *tls-ssl-ingress*) name should match the one specified in the deployment file of ingress.